# The limit of a sum

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, riemann-sum

I'm trying to find out this limit $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-\Large\frac{k\pi\sqrt{2}}{4n}}\left(\tan\frac{k\pi}{4n}\right)^2 =?$$
**My try:** I know I have to transform the sum into a Riemann sum, but I've found nothing useful. 
Any help would be great.

Comment: As a Riemann sum, we will need to identify the limits of integration if (to make things simple) we take the subintervals to be of length $1/n$ uniformly.  How many intervals are there?  This tells the length of the interval.

Comment: @hardmath We have $n$ intervals, the length is $\frac{\pi}{4n}$. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* You get, using a Riemann sum, as $n \longrightarrow  +\infty$,  $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-\Large\frac{\sqrt{2}\:k\pi}{4n}}\left(\tan\frac{k\pi}{4n}\right)^2 \longrightarrow  \frac{4}{\pi}\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}{4}}e^{-\sqrt{2}\:x}\left(\tan x\right)^2 dx$$

Comment: I've got a similar integral and I've no idea how to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: It might yield to integration by parts?

Comment: @B.Riemann: Using the fact that $\tan'x=\tan^2x+1$, and integrating by parts, the integral can be expressed in terms of $\displaystyle\int_0^\tfrac\pi4e^{-\sqrt2~x}\tan x~dx$ and known constants.